# AWS Lambda Java: Lambda was not able to unzip the file

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use Java with AWS Lambda. I created a jar file with all dependencies (using maven-assembly-plugin). Upon uploading, I cannot call the lambda. I receive the error `Calling the Invoke API failed with message: Lambda was not able to unzip the file`. The jar file is 11 MB. I can execute the jar with `java -jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maven-assemply-plugin` needs to be told to output a `zip`, not a `jar`. (I didn't even know there was a difference!)

Add this to its configuration:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     ...
     <configuration>
         ...
         <formats>
            <format>zip</format>
         </formats>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this because a JAR packed with the Shade plugin generated both the file and directory `META-INF\version\9`.

By excluding these files the JAR could be run again. The following is the configuration section for the maven-shade-plugin.

```
    <configuration>            
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <artifact>*:*</artifact>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/versions/9</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/versions/9/*</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </filter>
      </filters>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Worked pretty well

Answer (score 1):

The suffered from the same issue.

Generally, This error occurred if .zip or .jar file size of a lambda function is more than **50MB** after unzipping it

Make the sure that size of a lambda function code is less than **50MB**