# Lambda was not able to unzip the file

Tags: java, maven, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The file worked up until recently when updating a lambda however it started showing the following error:

```
Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Lambda was not able to unzip the file
```

I thought it might be because it is hitting the limits but the shaded jar is only 24.3 MB

I think it may be a corrupted jar however I don't know enough about maven to ensure it isn't a corrupted jar.

Any ideas on what I should do to fix/debug?

Plugins:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Duplicated not related as it is a year old and the solutions presented there do not solve my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Lambda Java: Lambda was not able to unzip the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50910812/aws-lambda-java-lambda-was-not-able-to-unzip-the-file)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-aws-lambda check for plugins

Comment: @amittn The plugins are correct

Comment: @MarsAtomic Did try the duplicate solutions but they did not work